# How to sum only one value from each duplicate entries

Tags: sql

I'm trying to sum a bunch of values but have a table with duplicate entries. Using distinct and sum with group by ended up summing all the values instead of only one from each UserID.

```
UserID | Value
1      | 200
1      | 200
1      | 200
2      | 500 
2      | 500 
2      | 500 
3      | 800
3      | 800
4      | 200
4      | 200
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
NumberOfUsers | Total
4             | 1700
```

Answer (score 6):

Do your `DISTINCT` first, then `SUM`:

```
SELECT Count(UserID) AS NumberOfUsers, SUM(Value) AS Total
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT UserID, Value
   FROM Table
  ) AS subqry
```

SQLFiddle example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/64748/3).

Comment: Agree that this is the answer if the duplicate rows are required. They might also want to look at whether it is necessary to have the duplicate rows. It may be a better solution to delete all duplicate rows and add a unique constraint to UserID.